# mosquitto openssl error: ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

When I use mosquitto to establish a TLS connection with my client program on a router, it doesn't work.

Here is the error log:

```
[21028.515924]~DLT~14068~INFO     ~FIFO /tmp/dlt cannot be opened. Retrying later...
1635324116: mosquitto version 1.6.9 starting
1635324116: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1635324116: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1635324116: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1635324132: New connection from 192.168.8.1 on port 8883.
1635324132: OpenSSL Error[0]: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
1635324132: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Here is my mosquitto.conf:

```
port 8883

cafile /mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/ca/ca.crt

certfile /mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/broker/broker.crt

keyfile /mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/broker/broker.key

require_certificate true

tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Here is my client SSL code:

```
ssl_opts.trustStore = "/mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/ca/ca.crt";
ssl_opts.keyStore = "/mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/client/client.crt";
ssl_opts.privateKey = "/mnt/d/Files/Desktop/Project/cert/client/client.key";
ssl_opts.enableServerCertAuth = 1;
ssl_opts.verify = 1;
ssl_opts.sslVersion = MQTT_SSL_VERSION_TLS_1_2;
```

Here is more specific code of my client:
[publisher.h](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/include/agent/Publisher.h)
[publisher.c](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/src/publisher.c)
[agent.c](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/src/agent.c)

Comment: Have you tried connecting with `mosquitto_sub` first? Also I suggest you add more of your client code so we can see all the options you are passing to the client

Comment: [publisher.h](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/include/agent/Publisher.h)
[publisher.c](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/src/publisher.c)
[agent.c](https://github.com/Ashechol/CPE/blob/dev/src/agent.c)

Comment: Edit the question to include the minimal viable version of the code, we won't follow links to off site resources to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTClient/html/_m_q_t_t_client_8h.html#a9a0518d9ca924d12c1329dbe3de5f2b6):

> An optional array of null-terminated strings specifying the servers to
> which the client will connect. Each string takes the form
> protocol://host:port. **protocol must be tcp or ssl**. For host, you can
> specify either an IP address or a host name. For instance, to connect
> to a server running on the local machines with the default MQTT port,
> specify tcp://localhost:1883. If this list is empty (the default), the
> server URI specified on MQTTClient_create() is used.

Make sure your URL starts with `ssl://` not just an IP address and port.

Comment: I add the ssl:// before the ip and port, the OpenSSL Error has been solved, but I get a new error: 1635384936: 
New connection from 192.168.8.1 on port 8883.
1635384936: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.